# Eclipse JDT AST: how to find a calling method returns value of an instance variable?

Tags: setter, getter, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

I'm using Eclipse JDT AST to parse a given java source code. While parsing the code, when it hits a method invocation, I want to find out whether that particular method returns or sets a value of an instance variable (basically to find out whether the callee method is a getter/setter of the same class of caller method).

E.g.:

```
public void test(){
  //when parsing the following line I want to check whether "getName"    
  //returns a value of an instance variable.
  String x = getName();

  //when parsing the following line I want to check whether "setName"          
  //sets the value of an instance variable.
  setName("some-name");
}
```

I've used the AST plugin also find out a possible path which would help me to refer it from the API, but couldn't.
Please let me know whether this is possible and if so, which approach that would help me to get the required information.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think that there is an api which tells you whether a method is a getter or a setter.

You will have to write code to do this. For a getter, you can probably simply check if the last statement in the method is a return statement which returns an instance variable.

Comment: Yes, you could check for trivial getters/setters, and if that's enough then its enough.  More complex getters/setters might do arbitrary computation, including caller a helper method in another class that actually does the setting.  To discover this kind of getter/setter, one needs full data flow analysis.  I'm not sure that JDT provides that kind of capability, and you don't want to write that yourself.

Comment: If the getters/setters are more complex, I would argue if they are getters/setters in the first place or not.